# Why is WKWebView not opening links with target=“_blank”?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

What is wrong with my code? Why is WKWebView not opening links with target=“_blank”? I want to open links that are opening in the new tab with the default browser. How Can this be achieved?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = "https://example.com"
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        self.webView.load(request)
        self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)

        // Page Scrolling - false or true
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

        // Open new tab links
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
            if let frame = navigationAction.targetFrame,
                frame.isMainFrame {
                return nil
            }
            // for _blank target or non-mainFrame target
            webView.load(navigationAction.request)
            return nil
        }

    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "loading" {
            if webView.isLoading {
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                activityIndicator.isHidden = false
            } else {
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                activityIndicator.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith` will never be called. You've hidden it _inside_ your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Where should it be put?

Comment: Not inside a function body.

Comment: Put it the same place you put viewDidLoad.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, But it is not opening it on safari, it is opening it in the app. I would like all new tab links to open in the default browser

Comment: Well that is not what your code says to do.

Comment: Okay. Can you help me out with that? Please

Comment: That’s not what you asked. The question was why the links don’t open. Do they open now? Then the problem is solved. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58813208/wkwebview-cant-open-mailto-tel-links     Can you help me with this question?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code for the question

```html
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let url = "https://example.com"
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        self.webView.load(request)
        self.webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
        
        // Page Scrolling - false or true
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        
    }
    
    // Open new tab links
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
       createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration,
       for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction,
       windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
      if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil, let url = navigationAction.request.url, let scheme = url.scheme {
        if ["http", "https", "mailto"].contains(where: { $0.caseInsensitiveCompare(scheme) == .orderedSame }) {
          UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
      }
      return nil
    }
    
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "loading" {
            if webView.isLoading {
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                activityIndicator.isHidden = false
            } else {
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                activityIndicator.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```